# Django - Url pattern regex not matching string parameter with accents

Tags: python, django

I'm having some trouble passing string arguments with accents to my Django application. I have the following url pattern:

```
url(r'^galeria/(?P<page>\d+)/(?P<order>\w+)/(?P<query>[\w|\W]+)', 'possible_brastemp.views.gallery_with_page_and_query'),
```

When I try a url like:

```
 http://127.0.0.1:8000/galeria/1/ultimos/Julian%20Andr%E9s
```

the pattern is not matched. I have isolated the problem to the '%E9' character (the '%20' doesn't break the match).

How can I change the regex to match parameters with encoded characters?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `%c3%a9` instead of `%e9` in the URL. The regex isn't failing... Django isn't even getting to the urlconf. Check the logs, you're probably getting 400 errors.

URI paths should contain UTF-8-encoded characters only. Any UTF-8 character that cannot be represented as a normal, printable ASCII character (and is not on the reserved list) should be percent-encoded.

`é` (U+00E9) is a multibyte character in UTF-8: `0xc3a9`. The percent-encoded form would be `%C3%A9`. The single byte 0xe9 is NOT a valid UTF-8 character.

See [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3).

`[\w|\W]+` successfully matches URLs containing `%C3%A9`. Django appears to percent-decode the URL byte string into a Unicode string, then converts it to UTF-8 for urlconf matching.