# Mezzanine - blog link is returning error page in ubuntu server

Tags: django, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04, mezzanine, ubuntu-server

I've created a web site using Mezzanine and some blog posts aren't open, when the user clicks in the link, the site show a error page. The problem is because the author used accent in the title (e.g. "Títle") so the slug is created with the accent. In my development environment I have no problem if I put or not an accent in any word, so I suspect the problem is in ubuntu server 14.04 configuration (my development computer is using pt_BR language, I've changed the server language too, but with no success). The funny part is that if I write the url without the accent (e.g. http://example.com/title) the blog post is shown correctly. Could someone show me a path to follow and solve this problem?

Comment: Please see here: [django-url-pattern-regex-not-matching-string-parameter-with-accents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695321/django-url-pattern-regex-not-matching-string-parameter-with-accents)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this issue](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/616) for the list of likely solutions:

- Make sure that you [created your production database with a `UTF-8` charset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/databases/#creating-your-database). This will cause headaches if you forget to do it.
- Verify that the system [locale](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/faq/troubleshooting/#i-m-getting-a-unicodedecodeerror-what-am-i-doing-wrong) supports UTF-8:

  > Your system locale may be a default ASCII locale, like the “C” locale on UNIX-like systems (can be checked by the locale command). If it’s the case, please refer to your system documentation to learn how you can change this to a UTF-8 locale.
- Verify that your wsgi handler (e.g., uwsgi, gunicorn) is being passed the right locale. Here's some [sample config](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/project_template/deploy/supervisor.conf.template):

  ```
  environment=LANG="%(locale)s",LC_ALL="%(locale)s",LC_LANG="%(locale)s"
  ```